# HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed Error in Django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-rest-framework

I have a file called calculator.py in which there is a function called calc() which has a method called calculate:[calculator.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tg2BB.png)

```
class calc():

    @classmethod
    def calculate(request_data):
        # start = time.time()

        results = {}
        a = 1

        return a
```

I need to give a POST request in the view,py and should display the variable a(i.e 1) from the calculator.py in the POST request. Below is the screenshot of my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.views.decorators.clickjacking import xframe_options_exempt
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer

from rest_framework.response import Response

from calculator import calc

import json

# local variables
debug = True


@xframe_options_exempt
@csrf_exempt
@api_view(['POST'])
def calculated(request):
    report_table = calc.calculate(data=request.data)

    return JsonResponse(report_table.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    #return JsonResponse({"data":report_table.data})
```

But when I run this program and check the API end point for the POST request, it is showing the following error..!
[API End point result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKsee.png)

```
GET /api/calculated
HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed
Allow: OPTIONS, POST
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{
    "detail": "Method \"GET\" not allowed."
}
```

Can someone help me, why am I getting this error. Is there anything wrong with this code..? 
I want the value '1', i.e being returned in calculate.py to be displayed in the API endpoint. Can someone help me with this..!? Please pardon me if I am using any terms wrong as I am new to Django framework. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try it

```
@api_view(['POST', 'GET'])
#                   ^^^^
```

Or do post request

More details [api_view](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/#api_view)

Comment: If I use `@api_view(['POST', 'GET'])` then I need to use another if condition as well for the POST method, but I only to POST it and need to just see whether the POST method is accessing `calculate` method from the `calc` class in the `calculator.py` file. Is there any way to see that..?

Answer (score 0):

When you load the page you are effectively making a GET request, you can drop to curl for example and try:

```
curl -i -XPOST http://container_ip:container_port/api/calculated
```

Usually though, POST request are intended to be used for changing the state of the resource on the server so if the only thing you have to do is retrieving data a GET is more appropriate